# Access XML nodes in parse string

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

I'm receiving XML from a server in a different domain, by performing an Ajax call through a PHP proxy (to work around the cross-origin "issue"). I don't get the value from the XML nodes into my html tag. No errors in my browser console. In Firebug, I can see the XML data just fine in both the Response and XML column. Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Flightinfo</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">
Get Flight ID</button>

<p id="fid"></p>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://d2f.no/flightinfo/proxy.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        address: "http://flydata.avinor.no/XmlFeed.asp?TimeFrom=1&TimeTo=7&airport=OSL&direction=D&lastUpdate=2016-03-10T15:03:00Z"
    },

    success: function myFunction(xml) {

  var x, i, xmlDoc, txt, parser;
  parser = new DOMParser(); // new Parser
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlDoc,"text/xml"); // Parse string
  txt = "";
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("flight_id");
  for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
  txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
  }

   document.getElementById("fid").innerHTML = txt;

}

  }); 
});  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Parts of the XML data received:

```
    <airport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://flydata.avinor.no/XmlFeed.xsd" name="OSL">
<flights lastUpdate="2016-04-07T00:37:16Z">
<flight uniqueID="5760860">
<airline>OSL</airline>
<flight_id>OSL424</flight_id>
<dom_int>D</dom_int>
<schedule_time>2016-03-10T10:15:00Z</schedule_time>
<arr_dep>D</arr_dep>
<airport>BDU</airport>
<gate>PAD</gate>
</flight>
<flight uniqueID="5758058">
<airline>AC</airline>
<flight_id>AC6377</flight_id>
<dom_int>S</dom_int>
<schedule_time>2016-03-11T05:30:00Z</schedule_time>
<arr_dep>D</arr_dep>
<airport>BRU</airport>
<check_in>10</check_in>
</flight>
```

[Link to XML feed](http://flydata.avinor.no/XmlFeed.asp?TimeFrom=1&TimeTo=7&airport=OSL&direction=D&lastUpdate=2016-03-10T15:03:00Z)

What am I missing here?

Comment: What if you just set  your `dataType` to `"XML"` in your AJAX request. You can just loop using jQuery. `$.parseXML(xml).find('flight_id').each(function(i,e){ doSomething(e) });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a streamlined approach, more the jQuery way:

```
<button type="button" id="load_btn">Get Flight IDs</button>

<p id="fid"></p>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#load_btn').click(function() {
        loadXMLDoc();
    });
});  

function loadXMLDoc() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://d2f.no/flightinfo/proxy.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            address: "http://flydata.avinor.no/XmlFeed.asp?TimeFrom=1&TimeTo=7&airport=OSL&direction=D&lastUpdate=2016-03-10T15:03:00Z"
        },

    })

    .done(function (xml) {

        var ids = $(xml).find('flight_id');

        var txt = "";
        $.each(ids, function(index) {
            txt += ids[index].textContent + "<br>";
        }); 
        $('#fid').html(txt);
    });
}
</script>
```

One problem in your code was the line:

```
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlDoc,"text/xml"); // Parse string
```

which uses xmlDoc twice. I believe you meant it to be:

```
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml"); // Parse string
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.8, [success has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in favor of .done.